# How to use Python Dictionary with empty keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following DataFrame, with an empty column called 'VEHICLE', and the 'Position' column has missing values.

df1:

| Position | VEHICLE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
|  |  |
| different value of 1 or 2 |  |

Is it posible to use a dictionary to get the following DataFrame?

df2:

| Position | VEHICLE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CAR |
| 2 | BIKE |
|  | BOAT |
| different value of 1 or 2 | TAXI |

Im trying to use a dictionary to fill the second DataFrame based on the values of the 'Position' column on the df1 DataFrame, but I don't know how to handle when the key of the dictionary is empty or when the key is different from any value.

How can I define for 'BOAT' and 'TAXI'?

```
dico = {1: 'CAR', 2: 'BIKE', '': 'BOAT', '??????': 'TAXI'}

df['VEHICLE'] = df['Position'].map(dico)
```

Comment: `df['VEHICLE'] = df['Position'].map(dico).fillna('TAXI')` - note: remove taxi from `dico`

Comment: When I use this, all the values of the 'VEHICLE' columns get filled with 'TAXI' :O

Comment: Then your values in `position` are not `ints` like your dictionary suggests but strings. And your empty cell is not an empty string `''` but probably contains whitespace (`' '`). You will need to look at the actual data values and create the dictionary accordingly - i.e., `df['Position'].values`

Comment: If I have a NaN value, is it equal to say that the cell is an empty string ' ' ?

Comment: No, empty strings are not the same as `NaN` use numpy's nan - `import numpy as np` and then `{np.nan: 'BOAT'}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(['1', '2', np.nan, 'something else'], columns=['Position'])
# create your dict
dico = {'1': 'CAR', '2': 'BIKE', np.nan: 'BOAT'}
# map you dict to the position
df['VEHICLE'] = df['Position'].map(dico).fillna('TAXI')
print(df)

         Position VEHICLE
0               1     CAR
1               2    BIKE
2             NaN    BOAT
3  something else    TAXI
```